# Android database values are not updating

Tags: android, json, database, sqlite, android-asynctask

I have values in JSON server URL and getting those values using JSON parser and storing into local device database and displaying into mobile device screen. When i run the app first time, it getting all the details from JSON server URL and storing into device database and displaying into mobile screen but when i update anything in server and again run the app it's not updating the values in local database and the database is not opening to write, it giving LogCat error of

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
```

```
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.example.bconspot/databases/BeaconDetails", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        db.updateBeaconDetails(beacondetailstore);
        checkDB.close();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database doesn't exist yet.
         db.insertBeaconDetails(beacondetailstore);
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
```

Logcat error:

```
12-15 17:23:17.555: E/SQLiteLog(17270): (14) cannot open file at line 32516 of [00bb9c9ce4]
12-15 17:23:17.555: E/SQLiteLog(17270): (14) os_unix.c:32516: (2) open(/data/data/com.example.beacon/databases/BeaconDetails) - 
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.beacon/databases/BeaconDetails'.
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:339)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:236)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:515)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:207)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:891)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:859)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at com.example.beacon.MainActivity$JsonTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:226)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at com.example.beacon.MainActivity$JsonTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Update:

```
public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

     public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            context = this.context;
        }


    Context context ;

        // All Static variables
        // Database Version
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        // Database Name
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BeaconDetails";        

        // Contacts table name
        //table 1
        private static final String TABLE_BEACON = "beacon_details";

public long updateBeaconDetails(BeaconDetails beacondetailstore) 
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_NAME,beacondetailstore.name);
        values.put(KEY_UUID,beacondetailstore.uuid);
        values.put(KEY_MAJOR_ID,beacondetailstore.major);
        values.put(KEY_MINOR_ID,beacondetailstore.minor);


         long rowId=db.update(TABLE_BEACON, values,null,null);

         db.close();
         return rowId;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to UPDATE database, why you use mode READONLY?

Comment: I referred in stackoverflow for the db is exist and i want to update. So,  i got above code then it's not working

Comment: What @MagicalPhoenixϡ is trying to tell you is that if you want to edit your database, you need to get a writable instance of it. opening it in READONLY won't let you edit the database.

Comment: I have changed OPEN_READWRITE. But still i'm facing same issue..

Comment: Only the update is not working if the database is exist

Answer (score 0):

You are opening your database in read only mode.
To open it on write mode try using OPEN_READWRITE instead.

Try to change the following line: OPEN_READONLY to OPEN_READWRITE

```
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.example.bconspot/databases/BeaconDetails", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
checkDB.updateBeaconDetails(beacondetailstore);
checkDB.close();
```

Comment: I have changed OPEN_READWRITE. But still i'm facing same issue.

Comment: Please post updateBeaconDetails() method.

Comment: please help on this..

Comment: change db to checkDB . Check my update @raj

Comment: No..you are wrong...error The method updateBeaconDetails(BeaconDetails) is undefined for the type SQLiteDatabase

Comment: when i update the table all the values are changing into NULL...can you please help me on this